# Move data from a external table to main table using procedure

Tags: sql-server

If I pass values manually instead of using variables the code works. But when I am passing parameters to the procedure the same code does not works.

```
ALTER PROC [OPTI].[Refreshfinal_GetAllActions] @RunDate [Varchar],@CN [Varchar] AS 
begin
begin tran
print 'deleteing records from Stage_GetAllActions'
delete from Opti.[Stage_GetAllActions] where Input_Date = @RunDate AND Country = @CN
print 'inserting records into Stage_GetAllActions'
insert into Opti.[Stage_GetAllActions]
select distinct
case when ltrim(rtrim(Country)) ='' then null else Country end,
case when ltrim(rtrim(Etl_Batch)) ='' then null else Etl_Batch end,
case when ltrim(rtrim(Input_Date)) ='' then null else Input_Date end,
case when ltrim(rtrim(ActionID)) ='' then null else ActionID end,
case when ltrim(rtrim(ActionName)) ='' then null else ActionName end,
case when ltrim(rtrim(Api_Executed_Datetime)) ='' then null else Api_Executed_Datetime end
from [Opti].[Ext_Stage_GetAllActions]
where Input_Date = @RunDate AND Country = @CN;
commit tran
end
```

The code is expected to transfer the data from the external table to the database table.

But it gives 0 rows affected even though data is there in the external table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have some implicit truncation happening, try explicitly defining varchar parameters size, eg. @RunDate [Varchar](30),@CN [Varchar](100).

Comment: Not "might have some implicit truncation"; absolutely does implicit truncation. [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). Good call. +1