# Database connection is busy with results from another command

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, azure, t-sql

What I am trying to do was to fetch data from an data API which I did using Python and the data that was received as response from the API, was stored in panda dataframe.

Then those dataframes were converted to csv and the csv was pushed to Azure blob storage.

The same program post pushing the csv to Azure creates an external table on MS-SQL Server.

Post which the data is transferred to main table from the external table.

This process is run in loop for multiple tables.  And the program breaks after few iterations.

The code for one of the procedures is available at this Stackoverflow post.
[Move data from a external table to main table using procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56952993/move-data-from-a-external-table-to-main-table-using-procedure)

This image is a screenshot of the error I am getting.
http://prntscr.com/ocxmwu

Comment: The short answer is: there is a bug in your application code so go debug it and find the error.  Until you find the problem area in your code, there isn't much anyone can do to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed by using

MARS_Connection=yes

In the connection string for database